# How to insert values in a table based on values in another table

Tags: sqlite

I need to insert extra records in one table for all entries in another table where a certain condition is not met, namely they do not exist yet in the table.

I have 3 tables, one is called `ARTICLES`, and has columns (`ArtNr`, `ArtName`), the second table is called `CUSTOMERS` with columns (`CustNr`, `CustName`, `CustAddress`)
The third table `CUSTARTLINK` is a link between the Customer and Article tables and has a record for each Customer and all Article is has. So it has columns (`CustNt`, `ArtNr`).

This way, in the application, when a customer is selected, only the articles will be shown that have a Link with the customer in the table .

All this functionality is working, including adding and deleting articles and customers in the resp. tables, and adding articles to customers (creating entries in the `CUSTARTLINK` table.

I want to add a functionality that I can select one Article from the Articles table and add this to ALL the customers existing in the CUSTOMERS table (so creating new entries in the `CUSTARTLINK` table, as long as they not already exist.

I tried to create this with the INSERT into command combined with a WHERE condition, but I am not getting close to what I want to reach.

Can anyone list the SQL commands to reach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you want to insert the `artnr = 11` for all customers:

```
insert into custartlink (custnr, artnr)
select c.custnr, 11
from customers c 
where not exists (
  select 1 from custartlink 
  where custnr = c.custnr and artnr = 11
)
```

The condition `where not exists...` makes sure that there will be no duplicates after the statement is executed, or if there is already a constraint in the table `custartlink` that there will be no error trying to violate the constraint. 
The same can be achieved with the use of `except`:

```
insert into custartlink (custnr, artnr)
select custnr, 11
from customers
except
select custnr, 11
from custartlink
where artnr = 11
```

If you have the article's name like `'art11'` and you want to use that and not the `artnr`, then you can do this:

```
insert into custartlink (custnr, artnr)
select 
  c.custnr, 
  (select artnr from articles where artname = 'art11')
from customers c
where not exists (
  select 1 from custartlink 
  where 
    custnr = c.custnr 
    and 
    artnr = (select artnr from articles where artname = 'art11')
)
```

Comment: Thank you forpas.  This looks very much like what I want to reach.  I will test it the next couple of days and let you know.  Many thanks.

Comment: Dear forpas, I just tested it and working fine, this is exactly what I need, thanks a lot. Would there be a preference using either of the 2 methods, except or not exists?

Comment: Usually NOT EXISTS is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO CUSTARTLINK (CustNt, ArtNr)
(SELECT CustNr, X from CUSTOMERS)
```

Replace X with article ID

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but will this not insert doubles into CUSTARTLINK?  Second question, the table CUSTOMERS does not have a column with the Art ID, so this will generate an Error;  correct?